# Make section number same as org-mode subheading

Tags: luatex, emacs, org-mode

I'm busy doing exercises in org-mode and exporting it to tex -> PDF.

How do I make sure it follows the headings set in the org file? As you can see in the pictures below, I skipped 1.1.3. In the PDF, it makes my 1.1.4 show as 1.1.3.

It shows correctly in the PDF Index/outline but not in the TOC or the subheadings.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Your code please!

Comment: @RaffaeleSantoro I don't have any latex or org-mode specific code. It's a plain org-mode file that I export to PDF. (If it matters, this is a default export on doom emacs).

Comment: Try to export to plain LaTeX with `org-latex-export-to-latex` and check the code producing the headings. With a small example file you could also post the resulting code here, as @RaffaeleSantoro mentioned. The fact that its Doom Emacs might be useful, but I don't use it and am not willing to skim through the specific Doom code sections which deal with org-mode and LaTeX-mode.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you added the numbering `1.1.1`, `1.1.2`, `1.1.4`, and `1.1.6` to the org heading manually since org is not numbering its headings automatically.

How should Latex or org know about your manual edits? Your manual numbers are no code. Latex just increases the `subsection` counter by one every time a new subheading appears. To alter the counter you can edit it manually after e.g. subsection `1.1.2` by inserting `@@latex: \setcounter{subsection}{3}@@` into your org file. Now, when the next subheading appears, Latex will increase it to `4`. Thus, subsection `4` should now follow after `2`. Of course, you've to do the same to jump from `4` to `6`.